# Windows doesn't respond to IPv6 multicast ping

Tags: windows, ipv6

I'm trying to do a IPv6 multi-cast ping from Linux and I can't get a response from my windows host.

`ping6 -I eth1 ff02::1` Will find all my Linux and iOS devices but not my Windows hosts.  I can find my windows hosts using `ip -6 neigh` or just straight up pinging with their link-local address.

Do I need to enable or disable something to get them to respond?

Comment: I can confirm this on my computer as well. Disabled Windows firewall and still no response. Won't even reply to the echo from local computer. Very interesting behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows has Connection profiles like "Private", and "Guest or Public" which manages if you can ping windows, or not.

You can see which profile is enabled for you with:

```
Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center
```

and click "Advanced sharing settings"

There you see wheter the "Private" or the "Guest or Public" Profile is enabled.
Beside the enabled Profile name is (current profile), that marks it as active.
Inside the Profile enable **"File and Printer sharing"**. And click "Save changes"

The "Guest or Public" profile is set to not respond to ping per default.
The "Private" profile responds to the ping by default.

To set the Connection Profile with powershell (in elevated mode) to Private use:

```
Set-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceAlias "*" -NetworkCategory Private
```

Comment: Hmm. This did not work for me on Windows 8.1. Despite being on a Private network with File and Printer Sharing enabled, Windows still does not respond to _multicast_ pings.